# There exist a function $u(x)\in C([0,1]),~ u(0)=u(1)=0$ such that $u \notin H_{0}^{1}((0,1))$?

Tags: sobolev-spaces

There exist a function $u(x)\in C([0,1]),~ u(0)=u(1)=0$ such that $u \notin H_{0}^{1}((0,1))$?
Justify your answer!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to find a differentiable function with derivative in $(0,1)$ not in $L^2([0,1])$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking if all of the properties of $H^1_0((0,1))$ are met for the following function:
$$
f(x) = x\sin\frac{\pi}{x}
$$

Intuition: construct an example of a continuous function,  it oscillates so much that its derivative may not be $L^2$-integrable.

Comment: Another example would be $f(x)=\sqrt{x}-x$, where the derivative blows up too much.

Comment: @AppliedSide That should be an answer.